# In Java, how to define a Future<V> that returns the best of several answers?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I need a value of type `V` that will have to be calculated asynchronously. Unfortunately, the best answer might take too long to calculate, so I have a couple of other values that I'll accept in a pinch. What I'd like to do is define a `Future<V>` that I can call with a timeout and have it return the best answer available in the time it had. Something like:

```
Future<V> theValue = // something involving executor.submit()
    // inside here, asynchronous calls to find
    V default = // something pretty quick to return
    V good = // something that will take longer and might not return in time
    V better = // something that will take longest but is the best answer

V v = theValue.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // now v should contain one of default,
    // good, or better, preferring them in the expected order
```

I'm sure this is a fairly common pattern, but I haven't been able to find a good example. Any help?

Comment: Using *three* futures might be a starting approach, although I'm not very sure a Future is a good pattern for this particular task.

Comment: I'd use three FutureTasks and block the main thread for the timeout. Then you check them for completion in order and cancel() all the others.

Comment: @user2864740 If you have a better suggestion, I'll take it.

Comment: @Fabian The only disadvantage of that is that if all three return early, you still have to wait for the timeout.

Comment: @TOB I would likely bypass the multiple Future's directly here - use the lower-level primitives and a single Future at the contract boundary *of* the "best result" operation.

Comment: @TOB True... You could still block for shorter periods of time in a loop. Doesn't sound like a very nice solution to me though.

Comment: This sounds like a candidate for a [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html), with a master task forking "default", "good" and "better" as [RecursiveTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html)s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the proposed scenario, there are three different versions of a computation (I will name them *good*, *better*, and *best*).  Each subsequent version produces a result that is preferred over the version before it, but due to increased complexity may take respectively longer amounts of time before completing. There is some arbitrary amount of time that the caller is willing to wait for any result, and in this answer I will use the value of *five(5) seconds* for that cutoff time.

It is possible to maintain this strict preference order while avoiding loops and queues by using a pair of [latches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for each batch of related operations.

---

#### Primary logic

```
ExecutorService execService = // ... e.g. new ThreadPoolExecutor(...)

<T> T compute(
    Callable<? extends T> good,
    Callable<? extends T> better,
    Callable<? extends T> best) {

    RelatedCallables calls = new RelatedCallables(); // new for each batch
    Future<T> bestResult = execService.submit(calls.wrap(best)); // first wrapped is primary
    Future<T> betterResult = execService.submit(calls.wrap(better));
    Future<T> goodResult = execService.submit(calls.wrap(good));

    try {
        if (!calls.awaitPrimary(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            calls.awaitAny(); // waits indefinitely, unless THIS thread interrupted
        }
        // reaching here means at least one of them has a result
        if (bestResult.isDone()) return bestResult.get();
        if (betterResult.isDone()) return betterResult.get();
        return goodResult.get();
    }
    catch (ExecutionException failedExecution) {
        // TODO: handling this is left as an exercise for the reader
        return null;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException interrupted) {
        // TODO: handling this is left as an exercise for the reader
        return null;
    }
    finally {
        boolean sendInterrupt = true; // or false, depending on your needs
        goodResult.cancel(sendInterrupt);
        betterResult.cancel(sendInterrupt);
        bestResult.cancel(sendInterrupt);
    }
}
```

This solution uses a helper class, `RelatedCallables` (detailed later below), to set up the relationship between the three computations submitted as `Callable` instances.  The helper class will *wrap* each instance, and the wrapper is submitted to the `ExecutorService` for parallel execution.  It is important in this implementation that the *best* `Callable` be wrapped *first*.  The order of wrapping and submitting the other instances is not important.

The combination of the `awaitPrimary` and `awaitAny` methods on the `RelatedCallables` helper, in conjunction with the `if` conditional, sets up our wait and timeout policy.  If the *best* (primary) result is available within the specified timeout, it skips the contents of the `if` block and proceed directly to returning results so the caller does not have to wait the full five seconds.

If `awaitPrimary` times out before the *best* computation completes, then it enters the *true* branch of the conditional and waits indefinitely for *any* computation to complete.  It is generally expected (but I do not assume) that *at least one* of the other computations will have completed during the primary wait time; if so, `awaitAny` will return immediately.  Instead of waiting indefinitely for one of the three computations, it is also possible to return `null`, a predetermined value, or throw an exception with some relatively minor tweaks.

Once the program flow passes the conditional block, it checks each `Future` in preference order and returns the value from the first one that indicates it has finished.  Also note that the `finally` block attempts to cancel any pending computations.

---

#### Helper (inner) class

```
static class RelatedCallables {
    private final CountDownLatch primaryLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private final CountDownLatch anyLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private boolean hasPrimary;

    void awaitAny() throws InterruptedException {
        anyLatch.await();
    }

    boolean awaitPrimary(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return primaryLatch.await(timeout, unit);
    }

    <T> Callable<T> wrap(final Callable<? extends T> original) {
        final boolean isPrimary = !hasPrimary;
        hasPrimary = true;

        return new Callable<T>() {
            @Override
            public T call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    return original.call();
                }
                finally {
                    anyLatch.countDown();
                    if (isPrimary) primaryLatch.countDown();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is a relatively simple `Callable` wrapper that chains to the wrapped instance.  Its main purpose is to decrement the `anyLatch` latch count after the wrapped instance completes.  That is how `awaitAny` will know if any of the callables wrapped by this helper have completed.

There is a second latch, used only with the *first* `Callable` submitted to `wrap`, that logically distinguishes the primary (or *best*) instance.  The wrapper for that instance decrements this separate latch so that `awaitPrimary` can time out quickly in the event that the *best* computation completes before the cutoff time expires.

Because `CountDownLatch` is not reusable, each distinct batch of `Callable` operations needs a new pair of latches.  In this implementation, that is accomplished by creating a *new instance* of `RelatedCallables` for every batch.

Comment: I used `invokeAll()` from `ExecutorService`, but the problem with that solution is that, even if the preferred computation returns quickly, one of the less preferred computations could block the main program. I think this solution is about the best you can do if you want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to hold the results

```
class MainClass {
  BlockingQueue<V> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();

  public V runMain(long timeoutInMillis) {
    DefaultSolution defaultSolution = new DefaultSolution(queue);
    GoodSolution goodSolution = new GoodSolution(queue);
    BestSolution bestSolution = new BestSolution(queue);

    // need an ExecutorService or something along those lines to run these in separate threads
    defaultSolution.run();
    goodSolution.run();
    bestSolution.run();

    int numberOfSolutions = 3;
    return checkQueue(numberOfSolutions, timeoutInMillis);
  }

  private V checkQueue(int numberOfSolutions, long timeoutInMillis) {
    V solution = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSolutions && timeoutInMillis > 0; i++) {
      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      V temp = queue.poll(timeoutInMillis, MILLISECONDS);
      if(temp != null) {
        // poll did not timeout
        solution = temp;
      } else {
        // poll timed out
        return solution;
      }
      // subtract time elapsed from timeout
      timeoutInMillis -= (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
    }
    return solution;
  }
}

class DefaultSolution implements Runnable {
  BlockingQueue<V> queue;

  DefaultSolution(BlockingQueue<V> queueParam) {
    queue = queueParam;
  }

  void run() {
    V solution = // compute solution
    // BlockingQueue will throw an exception if you try to add a null
    if(solution != null) queue.offer(solution);
  }
}
```

Your main class creates a `BlockingQueue<V>` and passes this as a parameter to the three `Solution` classes.  Each `Solution` puts its solution in the queue.  The main method blocks on the queue with a timeout (the `poll` method, which returns the head of the queue or `null` if it times out), then blocks again with a reduced timeout (the original timeout minus the time that has elapsed).

If you have a priori knowledge that `BestSolution` will always be better than `GoodSolution`, then you should modify `V` so that it indicates which `Solution` provided the solution - this is in case `BestSolution` somehow manages to compute its solution before `GoodSolution`, in which case the code as presented above will automatically overwrite `BestSolution's` early result with `GoodSolution's` later result (e.g. give `DefaultSolution` a priority of 0, `GoodSolution` a priority of 1, and `BestSolution` a priority of 2, and have `checkQueue` overwrite `solution` only if the new solution has a higher priority than the old solution).

Answer (score 0):

I think you *can* use three futures as Fabian supposed *without* the need to wait for the timeout if the better future is done earlier. Have a look at the `FallbackFuture` class in the following standalone example. It takes the better result if it is available and falls back to taking the good or default otherwise.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
        long tm = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Future<String> better = future(exec, "better", 900);
        Future<String> good = future(exec, "good", 600);
        Future<String> defaulT = future(exec, "default", 300);
        //FutureCompetition<String> f = new FutureCompetition<>(better, good, defaulT);
        FallbackFuture<String> f = new FallbackFuture<>(better, good, defaulT);
        int timeout = 5000;
        System.out.println(f.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        System.out.println("Took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - tm) + "ms");
        f.cancel(true);
        exec.shutdown();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}

public static class FallbackFuture<V> implements Future<V> {
    private final Future<V> first;
    private final Future<V>[] more;

    @SafeVarargs
    public FallbackFuture(Future<V> first, Future<V>... more) {
        this.first = first;
        this.more = more;
    }

    public V get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        try {
            return first.get(timeout, unit);
        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            for (Future<V> c : more) {
                try {
                    return c.get(0, unit);
                } catch (TimeoutException ex2) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        boolean b = first.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        for (Future<V> c : more)
            b |= c.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        for (Future<V> c : more)
            if (!c.isCancelled()) return false;
        return first.isCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDone() {
        for (Future<V> c : more)
            if (!c.isDone()) return false;
        return first.isDone();
    }

    @Override
    public V get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        return first.get();
    }
}

public static class FutureCompetition<V> {
    private final Future<V> first;
    private final Future<V>[] more;

    @SafeVarargs
    public FutureCompetition(Future<V> first, Future<V>... more) {
        this.first = first;
        this.more = more;
    }

    public V get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        try {
            return first.get(timeout, unit);
        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            for (Future<V> c : more) {
                try {
                    return c.get(0, unit);
                } catch (TimeoutException ex2) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        boolean b = first.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        for (Future<V> c : more)
            b |= c.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        return b;
    }
}

static Future<String> future(ExecutorService exec, final String retVal, final int delayMillis) {
    return exec.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delayMillis);
                return retVal;
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.err.println("interrupted " + retVal);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    });
}
```